# non-static member function reinterpret_cast failed

Tags: c++, member, non-static, reinterpret-cast

code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct item
{
   int f1() {}
   double f2() {}

   static int  g1() {}
   static double  g2() {}

   void f0();
};
void item::f0()
{
   auto c1 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(f2)>(f1);
   auto c2 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(g2)>(g1);

   auto c3 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&f2)>(f1);
   auto c4 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&g2)>(g1);
}
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
main.cpp|17|error: invalid use of non-static member function|
main.cpp|18|error: invalid cast from type ‘int (*)()’ to type ‘double()’|
main.cpp|20|error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&item::f2’ [-fpermissive]|
main.cpp|20|error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
```

my question:
The member functions passed as arguments will automatically convert to pointer, so i try casting the argument to a pointer, but still failed.
I don't understand why non-static member function doesn't work in all
situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You need to cast the return value of `f1`, not `f1`. Use:</strike>

```
  auto c1 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(f2())>(f1());
                                               ^^ Call the function
```

Make similar changes to the other lines.

I misunderstood what you were trying to do. The following should work:

```
   auto c1 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&item::f2)>(&item::f1);
   auto c2 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&g2)>(g1);

   auto c3 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&item::f2)>(&item::f1);
   auto c4 = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&g1)>(g2);
```

`f1` is a non-`static`member function. You can call it using `f1()`. However, without the function call syntax, non-static member functions don't automatically decay to a member function pointer. To get a member function pointer of the `struct`, you'll need to use `&item::f1`.

Comment: I want to get c1 to be a function, besides reinterpret_cast can't convert int to double

Comment: @R Sahu, wonderful! It works, but could you please explain why ?

Comment: @Gr.Five, hope the added explanation makes sense.